React Native Reanimated - How to compare shared value prop inside memo areEqualProps?
How to compare a SharedValue property inside memo callback?

_.isEqual(prevProps.animatedProgress, nextProps.animatedProgress)
prevProps.animatedProgress === nextProps.animatedProgress
_.isEqual(prevProps.animatedProgress.value, nextProps.animatedProgress.value)
prevProps.animatedProgress.value === nextProps.animatedProgress.value

Is this possible or not possible? Which one is the correct way?
I have been trying using lodash:
function arePropsEqual(prevProps, nextProps) {
  return _.isEqual(prevProps.animatedProgress, nextProps.animatedProgress)
}

But, sometimes, I get the error

Error: [Reanimated] Reading from _value directly is only possible on the UI runtime.

Also, when trying directly logging .value inside arePropsEqual, the result for the next property is not up to date (it shows the previous values).
function arePropsEqual(prevProps, nextProps) {
  console.log(nextProps.animatedProgress); // Logs the value of the previous render, not the new one.
}


SharedValue changes occur on the UI thread so you wont be able to monitor it changes with memo. If you want to calculate a value when a  sharedvalue changes use useDerivedValue. If you want to run some code when a shared value changes use useAnimatedReaction
